# Integrating $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(x+1)}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(x+1)}\mathrm{d}x$$

I've tried substituting $u = \sqrt{x}$ giving $\mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{2u}$ hence the integral becomes

$$2 \cdot\int \frac{1}{u^2(u^2+1)}\mathrm{d}u,$$ but after this I got stuck.

Any hints or help would be appreciated.

Regards
Aditya

Comment: What do you mean by $du=\frac{1}{2u}$? Why did you keep $dx$ after the change of variables? You also did the change of variables incorrectly.

Comment: But $(x+1) \to (u^2+1)$.

Comment: $2udu=dx$ and you get $2\int {\frac{1}{{u^2  + 1}}du}$. Your $du=\frac{1}{2u}$ is meaningless.

Comment: Agreed! Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Can you finish the problem now?

Comment: I still don't get how it reduces to $\frac{1}{u^2+1}$ tho

Comment: $dx=2u du$, $\sqrt{x}=u$, $x+1=u^2+1$. So $$
\int {\frac{1}{{\sqrt x (x + 1)}}dx}  = \int {\frac{1}{{u(u^2  + 1)}}2udu}  = 2\int {\frac{1}{{u^2  + 1}}du} .
$$

Comment: Ohh got it thank you

Answer (score 4):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(x+1)} d x &=2 \int \frac{1}{x+1} d (\sqrt{x}) \\
&=2 \int \frac{1}{(\sqrt{x})^{2}+1} d(\sqrt{x}) \\
&=2 \tan ^{-1}( \sqrt{x})+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: To be honest, I would not use the $d(\sqrt x)$ notation without any explanation in response to a user who apparently is not very experienced with integration. The answer would also be more helpful if you point out the error in the original calculation, instead of posting equations only.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach: Substitute $x = u^2$ to obtain

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(x+1)}\mathrm{d}x=\int \frac{1}{u(u^2+1)}\mathrm{d}x. $$

Now $\mathrm{d}x = 2u\cdot \mathrm{d}u$, and therefore

$$\int \frac{2}{ u^2+1 }\mathrm{d}u.$$
Let $u = \tan(a)$, then $\mathrm{d}u =\sec^2(a)\mathrm{d}a$. Thus,

$$\int \frac{2}{ \sec^2(a) }\sec^2(a)\mathrm{d}a=2\int \mathrm{d}a=2a+c.$$

Since $a = \arctan(u)$ and $u = \sqrt{x}$, the final answer is

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(x+1)}\mathrm{d}x=2 \arctan(\sqrt{x})+c.$$

Comment: $x=u^2$ is the same as $u=\sqrt x$ by the OP, so this is not another approach. The OP just did the substitution incorrectly. Also, please write proper sentences.

Comment: oops i haven't seen the comment sorry

Comment: I edited it for you. Can you see the difference in the quality of presentation?

Comment: yes thank you  Mr Gary I'm quite new  here